# how to make contents fit to div box by using css?

Tags: css

```css
body {margin:0;
      padding:0;}
      
img {width:100%;
     height:auto;}
     
a { text-decoration:none; }  

.box50 {width:50%;
        height:auto;
        float:left;}

#bigbox {width:100%;
         height:auto;
         display:block;
         overflow:hidden;}
         
.box50_tr {display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;}        

.box50_td {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigbox">
        <div class="box50">
            <img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_07.jpg">
        </div>
        
        <div class="box50">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline-block;">
                <tr class="box50_tr">
                    <td class="box50_td"><img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_08.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="box50_tr">
                    <td class="box50_td"><img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_09.jpg"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see, test_07 img not fit to #bigbox
and below of this img make empty space. :(

[image]

to make like this picture.
what should i do??
any help will be so appreciated!
thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your image `img {width: 100%; height: 100%;}`
2. Make your **bigbox** class **display: flex** .

Code below -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {margin:0;
      padding:0;}
      
    img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
     
a { text-decoration:none; }  

.box50 {width:50%;
        height:auto;
        float:left;}

#bigbox {width:100%;
         height:auto;
         display:block;
         overflow:hidden;
         display: flex;}
         
.box50_tr {display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;}        

.box50_td {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="bigbox">
    <div class="box50">
        <img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_07.jpg">
    </div>
    
    <div class="box50">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline-block;">
            <tr class="box50_tr">
                <td class="box50_td"><img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_08.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="box50_tr">
                <td class="box50_td"><img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_09.jpg"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Hossen! thanks for your help! :D really appreciate!! have a nice day! :D

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:inline-block;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_07.jpg">
                </a>
            </td>
        
            <td>    
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_08.jpg">
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_09.jpg">
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

finally i found the way!
but thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I have been trying to play with your code from the last half an hour or so, but game always remained. Finally I thought let's do it in CSS-Grid. This is by far a neater way to do it. Try once :)

Comment: Even in the above code... There is a gap in column 2, 2nd row. Same happens with Hossains answer. Check my answer. That will work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS-Grids, here is the neat way to do it with less HTML :)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#bigbox {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.box1 {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

.box2,
.box3 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.box2 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.box3 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Grid_Issue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bigbox">
      <div class="box1">
        <img
          src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_07.jpg"
          class="img-1"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="box2">
        <img
          src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_08.jpg"
          class="img-2"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="box3">
        <img
          src="https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/20201231/test_09.jpg"
          class="img-3"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```